# Substitute one field with other if its entry starts with specific letter

Tags: awk, gawk

If I have a file something like:

```
223 898 teeth
223 899 mouth
223 900 r9
445 800 round
```

My question is how can I use awk command to substitute column 2 with column 3, only for the row in which column 3 starts letter 'r'?
For substitution I can use gsub but I am not able get only to that row whose column three starts with 'r'.

I also tried using grep for finding word starting with r using :

```
grep "r*" filename | awk '{gsub($2,$3); print;}'
```

But this command substitutes column 2 to all the columns of that row.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /^r/ {$2 = $3}1' file
223 898 teeth
223 899 mouth
223 r9 r9
445 round round
```

This combines the searching and the printing into a single `awk` command, rather than have to make use of `grep` & `awk`. The above `$3 ~ /^r/` will find only lines where the 3rd field begins with a `r`.  In those situations `awk` will substitute the 3rd field for the 2nd field.

If the trailing `1` has you befuddled it's doing the following. It evaluates to true causing `awk` to perform its default operation, `{ print $0 }`.

#### References

- [Why does “1” in awk print the current line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262869/why-does-1-in-awk-print-the-current-line)